# Setting up Rethinkdb with bash command in docker-compose

Tags: docker-compose, rethinkdb

I am running a `rethinkdb` alongside a `.NET Core App` using `docker-compose`.
Is there any way so that i can set up 2 tables for `rethinkdb` and some secondary indexes?
Can `Rethinkdb` be configured (set up a `db`,`table`) directly with a bash command?

**docker-compose**

```
  version: "3.3"
  services:
      rethink:
        restart: always
        image: rethinkdb:2.3.6
        container_name: rethink0
        ports:   //i want to create a db,a table and a secondary index after set up
          - 8080:8080
        networks:
          - ret-net

      mp:
        build: ./mpserver
        image: mp
        restart: always
        container_name: mp0
        depends_on:
          - rethink
        ports:
          - 8203:8202
        networks:
          - ret-net
  networks:
   ret-net:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your best option is to setup the python driver and then you can run commands as bash script

```
sudo pip install rethinkdb
import rethinkdb as r
r.connect('localhost',28015).repl()
r.db_create('test').run()
r.db('test').table_create('myTable').run()
```

you can also consider building a docker image that includes this driver, i think the official image does not include it.

I cannot tell you confidently how to build a docker container like this, but based on [this description](https://hub.packtpub.com/deploy-rethinkdb-using-docker/) it should be something like:

```
FROM library/rethinkdb
apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y python-pip &&
RUN pip install rethinkdb
```

.. and the you can execute the creation commands from inside the docker container

```
docker exec -it <container name> <command>
```

Comment: So how should my `dockerfile` look like if i want it to come with python installed ?

Comment: check out the edit, i extended my answer, i cannot give you an end to end solution but hopefully you can put the pieces together. best luck ;)

Comment: But i do have to `RUN  apt-getupdate &&\ apt-get install .... etc` allin one `RUN` .So i must setup python first in the container, then feed the script then run.

Comment: should be possible to put them into one RUN